# What are the steps I need to follow to be able to write and edit python programs on my Android phone?

Tags: android, python, ide, sl4a

I'm a beginner, with programming and Python.

What I want to do is read and follow examples in books like 'Learn Python the Hard way' and 'Hello world: computer programmming for kids and others'.

I want to be able to do the example problems on my android (xperia arc) phone while I'm taking the bus and the train. The train goes through tunnels so this needs to work without internet. That means repl.it and ideone won't work (i think).

So far I have installed the SL4A scripting layer (I think - not sure how to check to make sure it's working) and I've installed P4A (python for android). What else do I need to be able to get a terminal/shell window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used SL4A for Python scripting quite a bit in the past, and it works very well with most of the standard modules. Once you've installed the SL4A app and the interpreters (P4A in this case), you can start writing python files right on the device.

The User Guide on the SL4A website does a pretty good job of introducing the basic concepts for using it: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/UserGuide. You can create a new .py script within the main menu. FWIW, you dont have to have a seperate "terminal/shell" to start scripts... you can launch them from within SL4A or even create shortcuts to launch them from home screen.

If you're not sure if the interpreter installed, try following this: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/InstallingInterpreters

** *EDIT* ** : If you're not sure if A4P got installed correctly, you can launch the app (Python for Android) on your device, and it will tell you the version of the interpreter installed, and how many scripts are currently loaded. You can also uninstall / re-install from there.

For what its worth, if you're just getting started with Python (and programming in general), I'd recommend trying to get some of the examples working on a desktop machine, just so you can get the knack of the language. If you use standard libraries, you can copy your scripts to your android device, and run them within P4A. "helloWorld.py" ports very easily ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I now have a shortcut to Python 2.6.2 interpreter but I may need a little more hand-holding, sorry. I ran P4A. It says Latest versions, interpereter:16, extras 14, scripts 13. Same for installed versions. What does that mean since it appears I only have 2 interpreters (shell and py2.6.2)? 

I also tried installing the PHP interpreter but that is giving me problems. Should I post that as a separate question? "FIX ME! implement getprotobyname() bionic/libc/bionic/stubs.c:378"

Comment: P4A is the interpreter for Python. By installing P4A, you've installed an additional interpreter for SL4A to use (it comes with shell by default). I haven't used anything beyond P4A, so I can't speak to the  PHP interpreter error? Sorry cant be more help there. 

As for P4A - interpreter version 16 is also what I've got installed at the moment. When you start SL4A, you should have a list of 13 scripts you run. hello_world.py is installed by default. When you click on the script in SL4A, it will give you the multiple options in a context menu (like "run" or "edit")